# On The Subject of Discolored Squares

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

<sup>(This is part of a series of puzzles written for [Timwi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1480/timwi?tab=profile) for a Secret Santa puzzle exchange, themed around various custom modules for the game *Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes*. No KTaNE knowledge is necessary for any of these puzzles except the final meta; each puzzle resolves to a single word or short phrase.)</sup>

---

## On The Subject of Discolored Squares

[image]

Comment: Eyy! I haven't seen Deus post a puzzle for a really long time. Looks cool!

Comment: Even without reading the question I gave it an instant vote up :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The hidden word is

> **Rhombus**.

Start by

> separating the red, green, and blue channels, revealing this pangram:
>
>  `SPHINXOFBL` `ACKQUARTZJ`  `UDGEMYVOW`

Using these,

> One possible set of letters in this font which overlay to produce the monochrome images is this:
>
>  [image: decoded]
>
>  `DONHE` `MACHT` `RIPAA`
>  `CCARA` `TIWME` `SONAR`
>  `MARAN` `CAMAN` `SIRRI`
>  `STANG` `VENKM` `SPENT`
>  `HUSTER` `THING` `MIMANT`
>  `GRYFFIN` `SLYTHER` `RAVENCL`
>  `ARRTSG` `DAAMAS` `ATHOI`
>
>  For the most part, the letters in a given cell are shown in no particular order, so they will need to be unscrambled.

Descrambling (with help from comments):

> `DONATello`, `RAPHAel`, `MICHElango` - Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles
>  `SCAREcrow`, `TINMAn`, `COWARdly lion` - Wizard of Oz characters
>  `MIRANda`, `CARRIe`, `SAMANtha` - Sex and the City characters
>  `STANTz`, `VENKMan`, `SPENGler` - Ghostbusters
>  `MISTERfantastic`, `THING`, `HUMANTorch` - Fantastic Four
>  `GRYFFINdor`, `SLYTHERin`, `RAVENCLaw` - Hogwarts houses
>  `ATHOS`, `ARAMIS`, `DARTAGnan` - Three Musketeers characters

Now

> each of these groups is three of a set of four. The missing members of each set, written here in the same way as the others of their group, are:
>
>  `LEONArdo`
>  `DOROThy`
>  `CHARLotte`
>  `ZEDDEmore`
>  `INVISIblegirl`
>  `HUFFLEPuff`
>  `PORTHOs`
>
>  Taking the first letter of each missing word that would have been cut off results in the word "RHOMBUS".
>
>  Thank you to hdsdv, Stiv, Matthew Jensen, Bass, and MacGyver88 for their comments picking up where I left off!

Comment: rot13(FGNAG, IRAXZ, FCRAT znxrf n yvggyr zber frafr gb zr.) Nice work.

Comment: The first row is rot13(QBANGryyb, ENCUNry, ZVPURynatryb - guerr bs gur sbhe Grrantr Zhgnag Avawn Ghegyrf)
And the second row is rot13(FPNERpebj, PBJNEqyl yvba, GVAZNa - guerr punenpgref sebz Gur Jvmneq bs Bm)
That's all I've got so far

Comment: The rest are rot13(Frk naq gur Pvgl, Tubfgohfgref, Snagnfgvp sbhe, naq gur Guerr Zhfxrgrref)  (for particularly large values of three).

Comment: And Row 3 is rot13(Frk naq gur Pvgl punenpgref: ZVENAqn, PNEEVr naq FNZNAgun) - now put them all together! :)

Comment: Note that these are all rot13(snzbhf sbhefbzrf zvffvat n sbhegu zrzore: Yrbaneqb, Qbebgul, Puneybggr, Mrqqrzber, Vaivfvoyr Jbzna, Uhssyrchss, Cbegubf. Abg fcbggvat nalguvat sebz gurve vavgvnyf whfg lrg, naq vg'f ragveryl cbffvoyr gur cnatenz jvyy pbzr onpx vagb guvf ntnva...)

Comment: For all but the last one, it seems to be three from a group of four, the remaining being rot13(Yrbaneqb, Qbebgul, Puneybggr, Mrqqrzber, Vaivfvoyr Tvey, Uhssyrchss)

Comment: Doing some research (I'm not familiar with the last category) it seems there is actually a fourth one.

Comment: The blank white space after each row is interesting. What happens when you rot13(gnxr gur svefg yrggre *nsgre* gur frdhrapr sebz gur zvffvat ryrzrag? Fb sbe rknzcyr, lbh pna gnxr gur 6gu yrggre bs jbeqf 1-4, naq gura gur 7gu, gura 8gu, gura 7gu. Lbh'yy trg n jbeq.)

Comment: Nice spot @hdsdv - you should probably write that up...

Comment: I don't feel like I contributed enough, when so much work went into getting to this point :)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I think we can call this one a team effort.

Comment: That's correct, nicely solved!

Answer (score 8):

Partial Progress.

Edit: Changed Image, because of new Puzzle Image.

> If you Filter the image by color, the top bar becomes `SPHINX OF BLACK QUARTZ JUDGE MY VOW`. This phrase being a well-known pangram. [image]

Will continue along this path and post when I get more.

Comment: It's interesting that the two 'U's appear to be different

Comment: @MatthewJensen Oh, good catch - that's an erratum, and it has been fixed. (The 'U' in the third line is the correct one.)

Comment: It kinda doesn't matter, in that the other one never appears.